# Javascript - Model find method for Mongodb Collection not work with filter conditions

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, loopback

I'm developing a project with Loopback framework and Mongodb. And I'm facing a problem about find document in Collection of Mongodb from application layer. It's not working with filter condition. I always get all document in Collection.

Here is my model schema

```
    {
  "name": "MyModel",
  "plural": "mymodel",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "title": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "description": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "guide_to_make": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "media": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": true
    },
    "price": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": true,
      "default": 0
    },
    "discount": {
      "type": "number",
      "default": 0
    },
    "status": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": true,
      "default": 1
    },
    "user_provider": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "create_at": {
      "type": "date",
      "required": true,
      "defaultFn": "now"
    },
    "last_update": {
      "type": "date",
      "required": true,
      "defaultFn": "now"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "WRITE",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$unauthenticated",
      "permission": "DENY"
    }
  ],
  "methods": {}
}
```

And here is some way which I used to query with filter to find items which match with filter conditions:

```
MyModel.find({user_provide:'5ae9e8400e59ae0ecc5ed614'},(err,items)=>{console.log(JSON.stringify(items))});

MyModel.find({user_provide:{'like':'5ae9e8400e59ae0ecc5ed614'}},(err,items)=>{console.log(JSON.stringify(items))});
```

Or I tried to directly used mongo connection as below :

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var dbo = db.db("asiodb");
        dbo.collection("Mymodel").find({}, { user_provider: '5ae9e8400e59ae0ecc5ed614' }).toArray(function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(result);
            db.close();
        });
    });
```

But with all ways which I used, I always got all documents in Collection. And I've tested with filter conditions in Robo3T with mongo query command

```
db.getCollection('Mymodel').find({user_provider:'5ae9e8400e59ae0ecc5ed614'})
```

And it's work as well with mongo command in Robo3T. It can find items which match with conditions
I don't know why it's not work on my server layer with JS code.

Someone kindly show to me what is wrong in JS code or the right syntax to use mongo find method.

Many thanks  !

Comment: Your key name is incorrect `user_provide`... It should be `user_provider`

Comment: I'm sorry, it's my mistake when copy code to stackoverflow. But in my program, it's user_provider exactly

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED:**

Using the node mongodb driver you should use your filter in the first parameter of the *find* function and not in the second, as you did in your code.

It should be something like this:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/asiodb";

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;

    db.collection('Mymodel').find({ user_provider : '5ae9e8400e59ae0ecc5ed614' }, {}).toArray(function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
        db.close();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, Mr. Tomas
user_provider is id field, but in another Collection, in this Collection this field just is string. And I've test with ObjectID('5ae9e8400e59ae0ecc5ed614'). I got same result, it get all documents in this collection and not work with filter conditions

Comment: @AcidBurn , I have just updated my answer. I believe this time it will work.